# Can anyone help me understand what this equation is?

Tags: exponentiation

Is there a way to express this equation where you have an integer $x$ and an integer $n$ and you do:

$$
x^n + x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + ... + x^{n-n}
$$

Is there a name for this type of equation and how can I write it more succinctly? I haven't done math in so long and don't even know how to search for this

Comment: It's not an equation, it's an expression. Most people would call it a polynomial and write it as $\sum_{i=0}^n x^i$.

Comment: What you wrote isn't an equation, however it is linked to sum of geometrical sequences with first term equal to one.

Comment: See at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple way, but in reverse order.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n x^i
$$

As a short explanation: $\sum$ is used to indicate summation.

Each value, starting at the one indicated below the symbol ( $0$ in this case) and then incremented by one until you reach the value above the symbol ( $n$ in this case) is used as indicated in the right hand expression (exponential in this case) and summed up with each increment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is called [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). In your case, you can verify that

$$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
Is the quantity you are looking for, except if $x=1$. If $x=1$ then you can deduce what is the result.

Comment: It is perhaps an initial segment of a geometric series, but it isn't a geometric series, not as defined at your link..

Comment: @rschwieb I think it would be OK to call this a  geometric series, Calling it a finite geometric series would be a little better. More formally, it's the sum of a finite geometric progression. But the answer as written is probably sufficient for what the OP needs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: @EthanBolker yeah, like I said, I’m just comparing it to what the user linked, which specifies “infinite.”

Comment: @EthanBolker at any rate the rest of the answer misapplied the formula for the infinite series to this finite one, so that needs correction too. I guess this is just a result of misreading the original question.